# spring boot latest CassandraClusterFactoryBean not found error

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

It seems like as per the latest spring data Cassandra distribution the class CassandraClusterFactoryBean is missing. how do I initialize the cluster? tried to look it up online but no help. can someone point me to an example?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Dupe here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74255599/112968