# java: cannot find symbol symbol: class CassandraClusterFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, pom.xml

I m developing spring cloud project based microservice.(packaging maven)I m using cassandra on docker image in project. I m taking error in CassandraConfiguration. I imported "import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraClusterFactoryBean;" in CassandraConfiguration  ,but I took error. Error Message in intellij idea. I tried to run this project on eclipse. I got an error again. Thank you!

```
java: cannot find symbol 
  symbol:   class Cassandra Cluster Factory Bean
  location: class com.accountservice.springcloudmicroserviceaccount.Configuration.CassandraConfiguration
```

```java
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraClusterFactoryBean;
and public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster(){
CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster=super.cluster();
cluster.setUsername(username);
cluster.setPassword(password);
return cluster;
}
```

I tried to do something pom.xml. I searched solve on this website, but I got an error again.
pom.xml

```xml
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.5</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.accountservice</groupId>
   <artifactId>springcloudmicroserviceaccount</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>springcloudmicroserviceaccount</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>17</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
         <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                  <source>19</source>
                  <target>19</target>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraClusterFactoryBean ,but still not resolved.

Comment: Hm. Seems like an older issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71962997/spring-boot-latest-cassandraclusterfactorybean-not-found-error

Comment: Thank you. I didnt see today. I searched on stackoverflow search place. I learned how use stackoverflow from you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CassandraClusterFactoryBean` was removed in 2019 with the migration to Cassandra driver 4. All details can be found in the original pull request on GitHub: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/pull/167

> Breaking changes:
>
> Removal of types (without replacement):
>
> - […]
> - CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean
> - […]
>
> ##### Configuration summary
>
> Driver 4 merges Cluster and Session objects into a single CqlSession object,
> *therefore all Cluster-related API was removed*. The Configuration was revised
> in large parts by removing most configuration items that were moved into
> DriverConfigLoader that is mostly file-based. This means that SocketOptions,
> AddressTranslator and many more options are configured now through other
> means.
>
> Further information:
>
> - https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.3/
> - https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.3/upgrade_guide/
>
> [emphasis mine]

More information quoted from the [upgrade guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.3/upgrade_guide/):

> `Cluster` does not exist anymore; the session is now the main component, initialized in a single step:
>
> ```
> CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder().build();
> session.execute("...");
> ```

Comment: Thank you . I looked inside the AbstractCassandraConfiguration class.  Then, I searched the cluster method. cassandraSession is now doing his duty. I am very sorry. Thank you very much. I should have been able to solve this error. My head stopped today. Solution;
 public CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandrasession() method.  import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CqlSessionFactoryBean;